# Enemy not showing in screen PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to do a game in python, I'm new to pygame, so I was following some tutorials, the player it's showing perfectly, but the enemy isn't showing. I've tried watching the tutorial multiple times, but I still have no clue of what it's happening.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#Titulo E Icono
pygame.display.set_caption("Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

enemyImage = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyX = 370
enemyY = 48
enemyX_change = 0



def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))

#Loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((59, 59, 59))   

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #Right Or Left Checker
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.5

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0

    
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <=0:
        playerX=0
    elif playerX >=736:
        playerX = 736


    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to call the `enemy` function. In addition, the events must be handled in the event loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((59, 59, 59))   

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
        #Right Or Left Checker
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <=0:
        playerX=0
    elif playerX >=736:
        playerX = 736

    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)            # <--- this is missing
    pygame.display.update()
```